# ROS Melodic python versions conflict (--unmet dependencies)

Tags: python, ubuntu-18.04, ros, dpkg

I have ROS-Melodic installed on my Ubuntu 18.04. It comes with python2.7 by default. And I installed python3.8 using the following steps by mistake -

```
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.8.0
cd Python-3.8.0
sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make altinstall
sudo apt update
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev libncurses5-dev libgdbm-dev libnss3-dev libssl-dev libreadline-dev libffi-dev wget
sudo make altinstall
```

After that, whatever I install or update on my terminal, it gives me Unmet Dependencies error -

```
$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
Hit:1 http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease                    
Hit:4 http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Hit:5 http://mirrors.piconets.webwerks.in/ubuntu-mirror/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                       
Hit:8 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fingerprint/fingerprint-gui/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Hit:10 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/micahflee/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease    
Hit:13 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease                         
Hit:14 http://wiki.jderobot.org/apt bionic InRelease                     
Reading package lists... Done                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
bzr : Depends: python:any
cython : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
      Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
      Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
googletest : Depends: python:any
libboost-mpi-python1.65.1 : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
                         Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                         Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
mercurial : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
         Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
         Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
mercurial-common : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-all : Depends: python (= 2.7.15~rc1-1) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
python-all-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.15~rc1-1) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
python-asn1crypto : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-attr : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-autobahn : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-automat : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-backports.functools-lru-cache : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                                    Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-bzrlib : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
             Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
python-cairo : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
            Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
            Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-catkin-pkg : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
python-catkin-pkg-modules : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
                         Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
python-cbor : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
           Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-cffi-backend : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
                   Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7~)
python-chardet : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-click : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
            Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-colorama : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-concurrent.futures : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                         Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-configobj : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
python-constantly : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-crypto : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
             Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-cryptography : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
                   Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-cycler : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-dateutil : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-dbus : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
           Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-defusedxml : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                 Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.15~rc1-1) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
python-docutils : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-empy : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-enum34 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
             Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-gi : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
         Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
         Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-gnupg : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
            Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-gobject-2 : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
                Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-gtk2 : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.6.6-7~)
python-httplib2 : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-hyperlink : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-idna : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-incremental : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                  Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-ipaddress : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-keyring : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
              Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-keyrings.alt : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-launchpadlib : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                   Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-lazr.restfulclient : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
                         Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-lazr.uri : Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
               Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
python-yaml : Depends: python (< 2.8) but 3.8.0-1 is installed
           Depends: python:any (< 2.8)
           Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any idea on how to solve this python versions conflict? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that when installing ros dependencies for python3 some of the original ros packages gets removed.
Normally the terminal gives a prompt "**that the following packages will be removed**" before removing them. But most people will not notice the prompt before installation and misses out.

Running installation command for ROS again is the solution as in following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full --fix-missing
```

You can try with the following commands while using python3 along with python2.7 which comes with ROS.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-rospkg*
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt update

# install ros again as some packages are removed while installing python3-rospkg*
sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full --fix-missing
```

Comment: Thanks @SujithRKumar for your reply. I was not trying to migrate ros-melodic from python2 to python3. I was trying to uninstall python3 by reinstalling it as explained [here][1] but It was not suitable answer for me because I already have ros-melodic pkgs configured with python2.7. That's why all this cause.
I solved it by removing python3.8 from update-alternatives, creating python3 symlink for default python3.6 and ran update-manager from which it allowed to run **partial-upgrade** (removing all ros melodic pkgs,python packages linked to ros).
[1] : https://askubuntu.com/a/1206924/1210885

Comment: Now my system is working as normal and I had to reinstall ros melodic.